# How to solve this nonlinear recurrence relations?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations, recursion

I know how to solve linear homogeneous and non-homogeneous recurrence relations. But today I found this problem.

$$F_1=1$$
$$F_2=7$$
$$F_3=13$$
$$F_n = 3F_{n-1} + k(F_{n-2}F_{n-3})+10$$

Where $k$ is a given number.
A friend of mine had this problem on a programming homework. And I wanted to impress him and told him there is a formula for this problem. But when I looked it more closely I realized it is not like other such problems that I have solved in discrete mathematics course, where we solved linear recurrence relations. So my question is could I find a formula for this recurrence relation and if I can how?

Comment: @Did that's the Laplace Transform, right? My guess, the product $F_{n-2}\times F_{n-3}$ spoils the fun.

Comment: Hmmm... Somehow, I missed the product. Sorry.

Comment: Doubt there is a simple formula here (as the growth is huge; and non-linear equations rarely have closed forms). As $n\to\infty$ we have $F_n \sim kF_{n-2}F_{n-3}$ so if $F_n \sim e^{g(n)}$ then $g(n) \sim g(n-2) + g(n-3) + \log(k)$ which has solutions on the form $g(n) \sim r^n$ for some $r \approx 1.32$ so asymptotically we will have $F_n \sim e^{r^n}$ (this is all very rough).

Comment: One can probably prove that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\log(\log(F_n))}{n} = \log(r)$ where $r$ is the real root of $r^3 - r - 1 = 0$

Comment: Thanks very much for the provided solutions. But I really couldn't understand them. I have only solved linear reccurence relations untill now. And I am first year computer science student I have taken classes in Discrete mathematics, Calculus 1 and Linear Algebra. How fast can I learn to solve nonlinear reccurence relations. And what I need to learn. Can you recomend me any courses or tutorials.

Comment: Linear recurrence problems necessarily have a closed form (if I am remembering correctly) and there are few others that we get lucky and we can solve as well... but generally speaking the non-linear cases won't have simple formulas. Just to echo what Winther said above...